# What role does the resistor play in this circuit?

Tags: resistors, discharge

[image]

This is a constant current discharge circuit. What role does the resistor play in this circuit?

Comment: The resistors makes the regulation slower. The R=220 in combination with Cgs of mosfets creates a delay time constant.

Comment: Oh yikes. This isn't a circuit, it's a smoke generator.

Answer (score 2):

Me being too lazy to create a schematic from the pictograph (these pictographs are difficult to understand the workings of the circuit), I would venture to guess that the resistors on the gates are to **prevent parasitic oscillation** at high frequencies (above 10 MHz) when the FETs are operating in the linear region.